# Creating a relationship between a composite key and foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm trying to link a foreign key to a composite key in mysql but im getting an error saying that the structure of the keys arent correct. I've checked the datatype and character length and both are correct.

Is this link even possible? see below for image...

Composite Key:
[image]

Foreign Key:
[image]

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained.

Comment: Oh sorry, i will for next time

Comment: Hi. (Obviously,) This is a faq. Please always google error messages & many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Not possible to create foreign key from composite key. Should be refer from parent key is primary key and should be not of column in reference key also..as per your share screen not possible to create this.. If you want to achieve this business let me reply will give suggestion to you..

Comment: I've sorted it. Thank you. It was what you said regarding the parent key

Comment: A FK can be declared on any set of columns that have any constraint. You may be trying to say that a FK must reference a PK or UNIQUE set. But you are not clear. Please use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

I had my composite key the wrong way round. I switched the 'UniqueCode' to act as the parent key and managed to link fine

Comment: Composite means more than one column. A FK must have the same number of columns as the PK or UNIQUE it references. It's not clear what you want in your question or how your answer gets it.